# Hidden Admin Account Appearing After Reboot

Tags: macos, administrator

I am new to Mac OS (using Mojave on a MacBook Air 2017) and am running into an issue. I want to create a hidden local admin account that only I know exists. I followed a guide and enabled users under ID 500 to be hidden and got that to work. I then changed login options  to "display name and password". When I logged out it seemed everything was fine. But after a reboot, both accounts showed up with their name. Is there anyway to prevent the admin account from showing up after a reboot?

Thanks all ~

Comment: If you have FileVault enabled, the authentication screen you see after restarting is not a regular login screen; it's a preboot authentication screen. It looks and works similarly, but there are a number of important differences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can disable file vault access for any accounts you don’t want to be capable to u lock FileVault or disable FileVault entirely.

The log in screen controls don’t govern FileVault since that renders from EFI before the os even starts.